Error 500 from my controller after calling a webservice
I have a controller that calls an external webservice (WS). When it calls the WS but this doen´t process anything because it´s already updated, it returns OK(200) and my controller returns success (AJAX). However, if the WS has to process an update and it takes a few minutes (not too long), it still returns OK(200) but my controller returns ERROR 500.
I also try calling the controller with a submit button, instead of AJAX, with the same result.
Hope I have explained well. Can anyone help?
callWebService controller
@PostMapping(value = "/xyz.htm", params="callWebService")
@ResponseBody
public String callWebService(final HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {   
        
    String resultado="{\"messageType\":\"error\",\"message\":\"Updated error\"}";

    try {
        SendNotification sendNotification = new SendNotification();
        if (SendNotification.send()) {
            resultado="{\"messageType\":\"info\",\"message\":\"Updated\"}";
        }   
    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("xyz.callWebService -- Error calling WS", e);
    }
    return resultado;
}

SendNotification class
public boolean send() throws Exception {
    String token = getToken();
    if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
         Client client = null;
         WebTarget myResource = null;
         Response res = null;
 
         try {
             client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(Conexiones.configurarSSL()).build();
             myResource = client.target(urlAvisos);
             Invocation.Builder builder = myResource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
             builder.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);
             res = builder.post(Entity.entity("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
             if (res.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase().equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                logger.error("sent - OK");
                return true;
             } else {
                logger.error("sent- not OK");
                return false;
             }

         } catch (Exception ex) {
             logger.error("SendNotification.send", ex);
         } finally {
             if (res != null) {
                 res.close();
             }
             if (client != null) {
                 client.close();
             }
         }
     } else {
        return false;
     }
 }


The HTTP client you are using (JAX-RS Client) may have a default timeout configuration that is too short. If the external service takes longer than this timeout to respond, it could result in an error.
So, try increasing the timeout settings for your HTTP client. For example:
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .sslContext(Conexiones.configurarSSL())
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // adjust as necessary
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // adjust as necessary
    .build();


Thank you. I also considered the timeout previously, I have tried this solution and set the timeout to 600 (and more) but I still have the same problem, Ajax returns ERROR 500.  However when I run it locally it works, so I´m not sure if there´s something else going on

Try to catch the time it requires to complete the request and possibly increase the timeout. Usually, accessing the organization's network locally causes such an issue.

The timeout is actually fine, the response from the WS is OK. I believe that the ERROR comes from the AJAX call to my controller, that´s where the error shows up. However,  I have also incremented that timeout and still fails. Maybe the problem is that there is a load balancing server, not sure what´s going on

One instance I recall is that database queries were successfully retrieved after a certain delay and returned the correct response when using a VPN connection. However, the application eventually triggered a timeout error, as the database connection was configured to complete the transaction within a set time limit of 30 or 60 seconds.

After much investigation I found out that the problem was actually the timeout of the Apache balancing the servers where the application is located (AJAX timeout was fine).
